# Checking if a browser has support for blind or partially-sighted people?

Tags: java, javascript, accessibility

How do I check (using Java or JavaScript) if a browser has support for blind or partially-sighted people?

Comment: What kind of support are you thinking about? What is your end goal?

Comment: But why? As far as I know, many screen reader programs hide behind normal user agents. How would you determine whether a browser is supported or not? What do you want to do?

Comment: because if it is supported.. i will change the content of my website..

Comment: @newbie - what would you change?   In most cases, it would not be considered best practice to make a change based on detection of an assistive technology, since you can't know for sure why/how it is being used.

Comment: I should add -- if I could detect an AT, I would, in order to include in our web analytics.   It could help us detect opportunities to improve the experience.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are looking to determine whether an assistive technology (like JAWS or Window-Eyes) are installed, no, you cannot with Javascript.   These technologies use OS-level APIs, and current browsers don't do anything that would cause their presence to be detectable.    There is a flash-based hack that can detect newer versions of screen readers see http://webaim.org/techniques/flash/techniques

> Perhaps you want to provide a different Flash interface or options if a user is using a screen reader. For instance, you may want to provide additional buttons or turn on self-voicing features when the person watching your movie is using a screen reader. You can detect screen readers using ActionScript. The Accessibility.isActive() function will return "true" if a screen reader that is capable of accessing Flash content is detected (currently only up-to-date versions of Window-Eyes, JAWS, and IBM Home Page Reader). For instance, you might add:

```
if (Accessibility.isActive()) { 
_root.selfVoicing.play(); 
}
```

> Important
>   Because there is a slight delay between when your movie begins and when the screen reader is detected, Accessibility.isActive() may incorrectly return false during the first few moments that your movie is playing. The Flash movie must also have focus in order for this to work. This can be solved by associating the ActionScript with a button within the Flash movie.
>   Finally, this method of detecting a screen reader, will not detect all screen readers. It will only detect the most recent versions of screen readers that support MSAA and have the Flash 6+ player installed.
>   This method is the only way of automatically detecting screen readers on the web. If you want to provide alternative content for screen reader users, you could use a Flash movie to detect the presence of a screen reader and redirect appropriately. However, this also assumes that the user has the Flash player installed (which most users do). If the user does not have Flash, then the detection will not work and the user might be presented with additional accessibility issues. Care must also be taken in providing alternative content for screen reader users. The alternative content must be kept up-to-date and provide the same information and functionality as the non-screen reader content. Here is the code to redirect based on screen reader presence:

```
if (Accessibility.isActive()) { 
getURL(screenreaderpage.htm); 
} else { 
getURL(normalpage.htm); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is there's no bulletproof way to do this. While the flash solution may work in some situations it isn't a good solution. I'm a totally blind programmer and since flash is generally so completely inaccessible I don't have it enabled by default in my browser. iPhones are used by a lot of blind individuals and for obvious reasons the flash solution won't work on them either. Even if the browser does support assistive technology that does not mean your site will be accessible. If your entire site is  JavaScript or WebGL that draws pictures onto a canvas it doesn’t matter how good the screen reader supporter in a browser is, there’s no way to provide information on dynamically created graphics unless the author provides textual descriptions of what is drawn to the screen. Ideally you would want to code your site in such a way that it can be used by both blind and sited individuals with no changes. If that doesn't work you could always put an invisible link to an alternative version of your site or other invisible content specific to screen readers that won't be displayed to sited users. For a discussion of creating content that is only visible to screen reader users see [this link](http://webaim.org/techniques/css/invisiblecontent/) For a general intro to web accessibility see http://webaim.org/intro/